# How to add strings from editText to a listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-edittext

I have a `MainActivity` with a `ListView` and an add `Button`. When the user clicks the add `Button` it takes you to another activity the `CreateActivity` for you to enter in data or strings into the editText boxes. After that you click the create `Button` and it adds the `strings` to the `ListView` it shows up, but every time I try to add another item to the `ListView` it just overrides the first item and doesn't add on to the `ListView`.

**MainActivity.java with listView and add button**

```
package com.example.brian.inventoryapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addButton;
    ListView itemListView;
    public static ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    public static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Bundle editTextData = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(editTextData != null){

            itemListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
            String data = editTextData.getString("data");
            arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList.add(data);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            itemListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            if(data != ""){

                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }


        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }

       });
    }

}
```

**activity_main xml with listView and add button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.brian.inventoryapp.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/addButton" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/itemListView"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CreateActivity.java with four editText boxes and create button**

```
package com.example.brian.inventoryapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static com.example.brian.inventoryapp.R.id.editTextItem;

public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextItem;
    EditText editTextModel;
    EditText editTextSerial;
    EditText editTextID;
    Button createButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getIntent();

        editTextItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextItem);
        editTextModel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextModel);
        editTextSerial = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSerial);
        editTextID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
        createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createButton);

        createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String item = "";
                item = editTextItem.getText().toString().trim() +
                              editTextModel.getText().toString().trim() +
                              editTextSerial.getText().toString().trim() +
                              editTextID.getText().toString().trim();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", item);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**activity_create xml with the four editText boxes and the create button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_create"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.brian.inventoryapp.CreateActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/editTextItem" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Model Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextItem"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/editTextModel" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Serial Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextModel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSerial" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextID"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextID"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSerial"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="ID Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSerial"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/createButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do not restart your main activity. Use **startactivityforresult()**. The reason why you think it overrides the first one is that you restarted the mainactivity and passing the one item.

Answer (score 0):

every time you restart the MainActivity, it is be created, the onCreate method  was executed .one method you can use the comment method：use startactivityforResult;
you can read this question [how to manage startactivityforResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android).the second method is to set MainActivity model to SingleInstance.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting MainActivity over and over again, clearing all data previously loaded.

Try this solution

Main activity:

```
package com.example.brian.inventoryapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int CREATE_REQUEST = 1;

    private Button addButton;
    private ListView itemListView;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        itemListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        itemListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CREATE_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String item = data.getStringExtra("data");
                arrayList.add(item);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
                itemListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your CreateActivity change `createButton` listener to this one:

```
 createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String item = "";
            item = editTextItem.getText().toString().trim() +
                    editTextModel.getText().toString().trim() +
                    editTextSerial.getText().toString().trim() +
                    editTextID.getText().toString().trim();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("data", item);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Updated my code, but app crashes on start giving me a fatal exception error.

Comment: Exception in Main currently trying to figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will assume as if the  MainActivity is started for the first time so you should use startActivityForResult() method instead of startActivity().This will continue your MainActivity and do not override your list View.